# Spring MVC request

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, request

How is it possible in a Spring MVC application using JSP to perform a number of n requests,where n is the number of data changes and to update the data in the JSP in real time after each change?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: *"Update the data in the JSP in real time"* - JSP's are transformed into HTML which are static (over simplifying this by leaps and bounds for sake of simplicity and space). Although your question is vague I think you should be looking JavaScript solutions. I thingk you should do some research on the relationship between JSP's, HTML and JavaScript and post a new questions once you have learned more about those 3.

Comment: Lets say I have 5 sets and some values ar moving from set to set for a number of n times and I want to display in real time how the values are moving between sets.

Answer (score 0):

What you want with JSP is kind of counter intuitive, since JSP uses server side page generation, while you want client generation.

A simple approach would using jquery and a rest API using Spring MVC.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/

You can use JSP to server the initial page and use JQuery to perform dynamic updates.